# Were the ancient Israelites of a darker skin tone?

Tags: history, bani-israel

I have seen ancient depictions of the
ancient Israelites and there features were
different than I expected.

Linguistic experts have stated that hebrew
is one of the early Asiatic-African
languages.

The hamitic people were a dark skinned
people, Noah's wife was hamitic, moses'
wife was hamitic, the ancient Israelites
mixed with hamitic egyptians for centuries
before exodus.

In Acts 21:37-38 the soldier mistakenly
took Paul for a hamitic egyptian. How
could the soldier mistake Paul for an
egyptian unless the ancient Israelites were
of a darker skin tone?

Also in Exodus 2:16-19 Moses was
mistaken for a Hamitic Egyptian. If Moses
was not physically identical to hamitic
people how could he have also been
mistaken for a Hamitic egyptian?

The egyptians of today are not the original
ancient egyptian but are of persian, arabic
and turkish stock, the orginal egyptians
were a Hamitic dark skinned people who
were conquered and exiled durring the
Islamic conquest.

I have been told by some muslim scholars that the jews that muhammed (peace be upon him) offered the Quran to were dark skinned people and that the jews of today are not the original hebrews (jews) but that the jews of today are the descendants of converts from around the year of 800 a.d and are khazarians to be exact not bloodline original jews that muhammad pbuh spoke to about Quran.

Is there any Early muslim references to the
physical identity of the ancient Israelites? or do any muslim historians know anything concerning this?

Comment: The question of [Ten Lost Tribes of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Lost_Tribes) might be helpful to your research.

Comment: Noah's wife was Hamitic? I'm pretty sure the [Hamites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamitic) were so-named because they were *descended* from Noah's son Ham, so unless Noah ended up marrying his own granddaughter, I think you have some facts confused.

Comment: @ goldPseudo, well Noah's wife was categorized as "Hamitic" being that Noah and his wife produced literally "black" offspring (Ham) so reasoning leads one to say that Noah's wife had to have been a person of "color" to produce "black" offspring (Ham and the Africans). Therefore she was categorized as such due to the probability of her physical traits based on the fact that she produced "Hamites" (black offspring).

Comment: @goldPseudo, also being that it has been declared impossible that someone "white" would produce literally "black" offspring.

Comment: @infatuated: David Duke is not just an "American conservative nationalist", he's a racist and I don't think his "research" should be quoted on StackExchange sites. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Duke

Comment: This Question is more about ethnology then Islam/Qur'an

Comment: @newenglander, I am familiar with Duke and his career including his past KKK association. But that article is properly backed up by verifiable scholarly citations.

Answer (score 1):

To know that we have to see family tree of prophet Ibrahim (Abraham) (A.S.)

Because we believe Ancient Israelites were originally are family of prophet Ibrahim (Abraham). As we know Ibrahim was born in eastern Mesopotamia. And in Islam we believe Ibrahim had two sons.

1. Ismail(Ishmael)
2. Ishaq(Isaac)

And Ishaq had a son Yaqub (Jacob) and Yaqub had a son Yusuf (Joseph).

Quran tells us the [**story of Yusuf**](http://www.sibtayn.com/en/?Itemid=615) where he (Yusuf) was brought to Egypt and how he met his father Yaqub there and then Musa (Moses) was sent to Israelites and Musa is also from the family of Yaqub.

As I have told you Ibrahim was from eastern Mesopotamia. We can see that the people of Mesopotamia have a fair skin tone. But yes there were many people who where darker skin tone who follow Musa because the message of all is for everyone.

Comment: If you're going to include an image, make sure to give a proper citation for it.  "design by Muslim scholars" is hardly sufficient.

Comment: Okay i will keep that in mind.

Comment: good answer, one thing I would like ti mention is what about the fact that the Israelites mixed with the Egyptians (taking Egyptian women as wives) for centuries before exodus, and Moses himself had a Hamitic (black) wife, Such mixing would render a darker skin tone among the Israelites.

Comment: Yes you are right but when we looking at family tree we always follow father, grandfather and so on. some people may have dark skin tone but most of them have fair skin tone but it we can not say they have white skin tone.